# how to print this text file data using only file:// protocoal

Tags: python, printing, urllib, urlopen

```
import urllib.request
data=urllib.request.urlopen("file:///D:/Learnign/pro/Code%20Editor/d.txt")
print(data)
```

Output:

```
<addinfourl at 1642793087856 whose fp = <_io.BufferedReader name='D:\\Learnign\\pro\\Code Editor\\d.txt'>>
```

How to solve this problem? How to print text file data?

Answer (score 0):

[`urllib.request.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) is designed so it could be used as context manager (see `with` keyword) so I would use something like

```
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen("file:///D:/Learnign/pro/Code%20Editor/d.txt") as f:
    print(data.read())
```

Note that it will probably return bytes, so you might need to decode it providing encoding used with given file, for example if it was UTF-8-encoded then print line might look as follows

```
print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Consult [`codecs` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) for list of supporting encodings.